# VBA Recordset says there is data, but me.recordsource says it is empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently i am working on a new report for an access application. The SQL command I am using to fill the RecordSource for the report pulls data in SQL/Server, it also pulls data when i run it using a recordset; but the RecordSource says that there is no data.

My question is, is there anything I am doing/not doing that would cause the SQL command to not return data when set to the RecordSource of the Report?

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)


gs = "SELECT dbo.tblSubGrant.intAutoRecNum "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intSubGrantID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrant.vcEncumbranceNumber "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrant.intFiscalYearID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.v_InstitutionAllType.exprInstitutionName "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblGrantAwardType.vcGrantAwardTypeDescription "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.vcSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeDescription "
gs = gs & ", aSubGrantListAmt.ExprAmtAward "
gs = gs & ", CASE WHEN dbo.tblSubGrant.bitHoldClaim = 1 THEN 'OnHold' WHEN dbo.tblSubGrant.bitClosed = 1 THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'OPEN' END AS Status "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intInstitutionEmployeeID "
gs = gs & "FROM dbo.tblSubGrant WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "INNER JOIN dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblSubGrant.intSubGrantID = dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intSubGrantID "
gs = gs & "INNER JOIN dbo.tblGrantAwardAwardTypeAllocation WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblSubGrant.intGrantAwardAwardTypeAllocationID = dbo.tblGrantAwardAwardTypeAllocation.intGrantAwardAwardTypeAllocationID "
gs = gs & "INNER JOIN dbo.tblGrantAwardType WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblGrantAwardAwardTypeAllocation.intGrantAwardTypeID = dbo.tblGrantAwardType.intGrantAwardTypeID "
gs = gs & "INNER JOIN dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID = dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID "
gs = gs & "LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_InstitutionAllType WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblSubGrant.intInstitutionRecipientID = dbo.v_InstitutionAllType.ID "
gs = gs & "LEFT OUTER JOIN "
gs = gs & "(SELECT SUM (dbo.v_frmSubGrantListAmt.exprOrig) + SUM(dbo.v_frmSubGrantListAmt.exprSup) - SUM(dbo.v_frmSubGrantListAmt.exprRed) - SUM(dbo.v_frmSubGrantListAmt.exprLiq)  AS ExprAmtAward "
gs = gs & ", intSubGrantID "
gs = gs & "FROM v_frmSubGrantListAmt WITH(NOLOCK) "
gs = gs & "GROUP BY intSubGrantID) aSubGrantListAmt "
gs = gs & "ON dbo.tblSubGrant.intSubGrantID = aSubGrantListAmt.intSubGrantID "
gs = gs & "GROUP BY dbo.tblSubGrant.intAutoRecNum "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intSubGrantID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrant.intFiscalYearID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.v_InstitutionAllType.exprInstitutionName "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblGrantAwardType.vcGrantAwardTypeDescription "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.vcSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeDescription "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrant.vcEncumbranceNumber "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intInstitutionEmployeeID "
gs = gs & ", CASE WHEN bitHoldClaim = 1 THEN 'OnHold' WHEN bitClosed = 1 THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'OPEN' END "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrant.intInstitutionRecipientID "
gs = gs & ", dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID "
gs = gs & ", aSubGrantListAmt.ExprAmtAward "
gs = gs & "HAVING dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContact.intInstitutionEmployeeID = " & Forms!frmBULKContactUpdate!intInstitutionEmployeeID & " "
gs = gs & "AND (CASE WHEN dbo.tblSubGrant.bitHoldClaim = 1 THEN 'OnHold' WHEN dbo.tblSubGrant.bitClosed = 1 THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'OPEN' END = 'OPEN') "
gs = gs & "AND dbo.tblSubGrantInstitutionContactType.intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID = " & Forms!frmBULKContactUpdate!intSubGrantInstitutionContactTypeID & " "
gs = gs & "ORDER BY 5, 3 "


Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open gs, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Me.RecordSource = gs
DoEvents

rst.Close
cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding the problem.  In your case it turns out to be only a debugging issue, an oversight.  (Your question code doesn't even show the portion that you fixed... with a call to DoCmd.OpenReport)  Your query is also rather long and so the question will not likely contribute to helping anyone in the future.  In such a case, you might consider deleting the entire question, or perhaps only commenting that you fixed it rather than an answer.  I am aware that you are limited right now as a new user, so this is for future reference. By all means, please return with new questions!

Comment: I know, since it is ancient code 15+ years old, i got it working the way it was written, then i converted it to a view to limit the length of the call.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Since i was no longer setting the SQL command to the RecordSource in the Report properties directly, i forgot to remove the Criteria portion from the call to the DoCmd.OpenReport gstrDocName, acViewPreview. It was trying to add on a WHERE clause to the SQL command.